# How to add where not null condition to cron job in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron

In my Laravel-5.8, I have a cron job running.

```
public function handle()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.laravel.com/my-workers', [
       'query' => ['key' => 'kkdfhfn7755222']
   ])->getBody();

    $clientdatas = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);  
    
    foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
    {        
     
        $testing = HrTesting::updateOrCreate([
            'testing_name' => $clientdata['testing_location']
        ],
        [
                 'company_id'   => 1,          
        ]); 
    }

   }
```

I found that where $clientdata['testing_location']   is null, it still creates/updates it in the table.

How do I put it that where null, it should not perform any action?

Thanks

Comment: So, mybe you need to add `if($clientdata['testing_location'] === null) { continue; }` inside `foreach` loop? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply add it to your foreach loop.

```
    foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
    {        
        if (isset($clientdata['testing_location']) && $clientdata['testing_location'] !== null) { 
            $testing = HrTesting::updateOrCreate([
                'testing_name' => $clientdata['testing_location']
            ],[
                 'company_id'   => 1,          
            ]); 
        }
    }
```